# Numbers to letters in java (like old mobile phones' keyboard)

Tags: java, string, numbers, letters

Just like older mobile phones' keypads work. I should input a string of numbers and the program should print out a text based on those numbers.

e.g: Input: 4448 9666777557777 should output to: ITWORKS.

Here's my code so far but it's not printing out anything. Could you please tell me what's wrong with it and what could've I done better?

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] letters = {
            "0",
            "1",
            "ABC",
            "DEF",
            "GHI",
            "JKL",
            "MNO",
            "PQRS",
            "TUV",
            "WXYZ"
    };

    System.out.println("Write something.");
    String numbers = sc.nextLine();

    char[] toChar = numbers.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < toChar.length; index++) {
        if (toChar[index] >= '2' && toChar[index] <= '9') {
            if (index > 0 && toChar[index] == toChar[index - 1]) {
                count++;
            }
            else if (count > 0) {
                System.out.print(letters[toChar[index - 1] - '0'].charAt(count - 1));
                count = 0;              
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Think what happens if a telephone number have 2 same digits one after another. Should for example `7777` be projected into one `S` (7777) or two `Q`s (77 + 77), or maybe it is `PR` (7 + 777)...

Comment: I'm pretty sure (7777) should always equal to S, (77777) to SP, (777777) to SQ, etc.

Comment: Using this kind of encoding there is no way to get `QR` or `PS` for example (because they both will be encoded to `77777` and decoded into `SQ`)

Comment: Oh, yes. I understand. Well... When I think about it now `77777` should equal to `P` - a.k.a rotate around the 4 letters until it sees a number != 7.

Comment: Did you see my answer? It solves all the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private static final String[] letters = {
            "0", "1", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQRS", "TUV", "WXYZ"
    };

    private static char getChar(int digit, int count) {
        while (count > letters[digit].length()) {
            count -= letters[digit].length();
        }

        return letters[digit].charAt(count - 1);
    }

    private static String getString(String input) {
        int lastDigit = 0, count = 1;
        String result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            int currentDigit = input.charAt(i) - '0';
            if (currentDigit >= 2 && currentDigit <= 9) {
                if (lastDigit == 0) {
                    lastDigit = currentDigit;
                } else if (currentDigit == lastDigit) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    result += getChar(lastDigit, count);

                    lastDigit = currentDigit;
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return result + getChar(lastDigit, count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Write something");
            System.out.println(getString(scanner.nextLine()));
        }
    }
}
```

I enhanced the problem decomposition. It works for all examples OP has shown so far.

Comment: Thank you! Accepted your answer. It's similar to mine as an idea yet works flawlessly! Could you please explain why do you return `result + getChar(lastDigit, count)` at the end instead of simply `result`, though?

Comment: Well, for the last sequence of the input, it doesn't reach the "else" part of that condition. The code, how it is, basically "reacts" on the change -- a new digit (e.g.: "777|8..." - 8 is the change). For the last sequence of the input, such change doesn't occur. It'd be possible to change the code so it evaluates the 'else' part on change OR end of string.

Comment: Do you have any idea how could I possibly introduce intervals ' ' as delimiters in the aforementioned code, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention correctly, `count` should increment only if current digit is the same as previous:

```
for (int pos = 1, char c = toChar[0], int count = 1; pos <= toChar.length; pos++, count = 1) {

   int n = letters[c - '0'].length;
   while (pos < toChar.length && c == toChar[pos] && count < n) {
       pos++;
       count++;
   }
   System.out.println(letters[c - '0'].charAt(count - 1));
   if (pos < toChar.length - 1) {
       c = toChar[++pos];
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks great but for `2` it doesn't print anything. `22` works fine, outputs `B`, but `2233` outputs `BD` instead of `BE`.

Comment: forgot to reassign `c` in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you!
Check this one

```
public class Denene {
    public static String getChar(String cha)
    {
        String [] chars= {"0","1","abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};
        String[] strSplit = cha.split(" "); //7777 88 7777 2 66 8
        int len=strSplit.length;
        char r;
        char []ar =new char[len];
      for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
          String str=strSplit[i];
          ar[i]= chars[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)))].charAt(str.length()-1);
        }
        return new String(ar);
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Enter any number .....");
           System.out.println(getChar(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine())); //Output : susant
        }
    }
```